# GWT: gwt-material-addins: MaterialCarousel: Your carousel container is not yet initialized

Tags: gwt, material-design, carousel

I am trying to use MaterialCarousel in my sample project and it is throwing me an error only while running. But the compilation is going through successfully.

Here are the versions:
Java - 1.8 | GWT - 2.8.11 | MaterialDesign - 2.1.1

I am inheriting only:

```
<inherits name="gwt.material.design.addins.GwtMaterialAddins" />
```

Here is my code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    MaterialCarousel carousel = new MaterialCarousel();
    carousel.add(new Label("sdasdasd"));
    carousel.add(new Label("sdasdasd"));
    RootPanel.get().clear();
    RootPanel.get().add(carousel);
}
```

I have the following libraries in the build path.

gwt-material-2.1.1.jar
gwt-material-addins-2.1.1.jar
gwt-material-jquery-2.1.1.jar

Following is the error:

```
19:33:02.571 [ERROR] [gwtcuriositypc] Your carousel container is not yet initialized
java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at gwt.material.design.addins.client.carousel.MaterialCarousel.command(MaterialCarousel.java:275)
    at gwt.material.design.addins.client.carousel.MaterialCarousel.add(MaterialCarousel.java:206)
    at org.vadiraj.curiosity.client.GWTCuriosityPC.onModuleLoad(GWTCuriosityPC.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:423)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:530)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can somebody please help me what is going on?

Comment: Have you got the SlickJS dependency added?

Comment: No. Can you please explain me what is it and why is it needed? Also, how to add that dependency to my GWT project?

Comment: I have asked the question two months ago and I haven't received any useful answer. Looks like somebody has already encountered the same problem 2 years ago. 


[link]https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material/issues/561

**@perdi Estaquel will you be able to help me?**

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the answer. Does this happen only in dev mode? The problem looks like one of those "nice little black box stopped being nice". So my rough-and-ready workaround would be to forget how the framework does things, and just add the SlickJS javascript lib link directly in your web page.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see in your logs in that the container (carousel) is not yet constructed, to solve this:

- First you have to create the MaterialCarousel (and add it to your RootPanel) in the constructor of your class/widget,
- Next, in the onModuleLoad, add the different labels and panels (work for me)
  Hope it helps

Comment: This is my code present in the constructor

`MaterialCarousel car = new MaterialCarousel();`
`Window.alert("is attached - " + car.isAttached()); // Displays false`
`Window.alert("Adding to RootPanel");`
`RootPanel.get().add(car);`
`Window.alert("Added to RootPanel"); // This alert statement never gets executed`

@Perdi Can you please tell me how to add SlickJS as a dependency?